# Flutter not upgrade especifics packs

Tags: flutter

why flutter not upgrade own packs?
My project start normaly but when i try upgrade the packs, only two not upgrade.

- material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
- meta 1.9.1 (1.10.0 available)

[image]

I removed pubspec.lock but i not have success in upgrade these two packs.

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: lumi
description: Lumi
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev
homepage: ''
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.1.0-83.0.dev <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  isoft:
    path: ../../isoft

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - assets/images/
  fonts:
    - family: Inconsolata
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inconsolata-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inconsolata-Medium.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inconsolata-SemiBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Inconsolata-Bold.ttf
    - family: RobotoMono
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoMono-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoMono-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoMono-SemiBold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoMono-Medium.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/RobotoMono-SemiBoldItalic.ttf
          weight: 700
```

Comment: I would like update this packs and no use olds versions.

Comment: Please include your `pubspec.yaml` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

As the message says, there might be some dependency constraints, meaning some package, maybe even directly yours, requires specific version of one of those packages.

Check if your [`pubspec.yaml`](https://docs.flutter.dev/tools/pubspec) has dash (`^`) before version names, like:

```
meta: ^1.0.5
```

The dash before version name means your package would be compatible with all minor versions of current major versions (`1.*`). You can read more at [Dart.dev article about versioning](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/versioning).